# How to populate accordion with firebase data?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing a web page that will obtain data from my firestore collection and display each document with its corresponding fields and populate my accordion with data from the firebase however there is nothing being displayed

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });


    window.onload = function () {

      var storageName = localStorage.getItem("storageName");
      console.log(storageName);

        db.collection(`${storageName}`).get().then((snapshot) => {

            // $("#heading").html(""); // This will empty your heading
            // $("#forward").html(""); // This will empty your station box
            var n = 0;

            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                var name_loc = child.id;
                var forward = child.data().ForwardPower;
                var reflected = child.data().Reflectedpower;
                var ups = child.data().UPSError;
                var upsDesc = child.data().UPSDesc;
                var trans = child.data().TransmitterError;
                var transDesc = child.data().TransDesc;

                $("#acc").append(`
                <article>
                    <h1 data-accordion-element-trigger >`+  child.id +`</h1>
                    <div data-accordion-element-content class="content" data-parent="#acc">
                        <p> Forward Power: `+  child.data().ForwardPower +`</p>
                        <p> Reflected Power: `+  child.data().Reflectedpower +`</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                `);
            n += 1;

            })

        })
    }

</script>



</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section id="acc" class="card">
  <article id="accordion">
    <h1 data-accordion-element-trigger id="heading"></h1>
    <div data-accordion-element-content class="content">
        <p id="forward"></p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

On running the code, the accordion is being displayed as follows. I can't see the document fields and clicking on any button has no effect
Image: [accordion image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIMQd.png)

Comment: Did u add jquery? The error is here `$("#acc").append(` this is jquery syntax to access an id

Comment: Just seen. Thanks. I cant believe I forgot to add jquery

Comment: However I'm now facing another issue, the accordion wont open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add   jquery library before your script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: However, I'm now facing another issue, the accordion wont open

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample image of the problem